# Extending blade template for opening and closing tags

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to wrap my head around extending blade templates in Laravel 4.2, the example in the docs states:

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('datetime');

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo $2->format(\'m/d/Y H:i\'); ?>', $view);
});
```

This works for single blade tags such `@datetime(...)`.

I'm trying to extend (more like alias) something such as

```
@if($var == 'foo')

 bar

@endif
```

to

```
@foo

 bar

@endfoo
```

I'm unsure how to handle "opening" and "closing" tags. Can someone show me an example?

Comment: Can you please add a specific php syntax which you would like to convert to blade syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file `blade_extensions.php` in your `app/` folder. Then inside that file put the following:

```
<?php

Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('foo');

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php if ($2 == "foo") : ?>', $view);
});

Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createPlainMatcher('endfoo');

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php endif; ?>', $view);
});
```

Then in your `app/start/global.php` at the bottom after `require app_path().'/filters.php';` add:

```
require app_path().'/blade_extensions.php';
```

Then in your view you can write the following:

```
@foo ($var)
  bar
@endfoo
```

I don't know if that's exactly the control structure you're looking for, but that matches the check for `$var == 'foo'`